# Scrapy - Limiting the URLs crawled

Tags: regex, scrapy

I am crawling Erowid and trying to gather data from the site. The spider I coded

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector



class ExperiencesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "experiences"
    allowed_domains = ["www.erowid.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.erowid.org/experiences/exp_list.shtml']
    rules = [ 
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('subs/exp_\w+.shtml')), follow = True)    
    ]
    def parse_item(self, response):
        pass
```

The thing is that the spider will crawl not only to a site I want such as 
https://www.erowid.org/experiences/subs/exp_aPVP.shtml
(which gives all the describtions that I need)
but will also crawl into subsections of that site such as https://www.erowid.org/experiences/subs/exp_aPVP_General.shtml which is a subsection of the code I need.

I am trying to edit my code such that it will reject anything with an underscore under it which I thought \w+ would do but didn't. I tried using [a-z]+ but that stopped the spider all together.

What would be the proper regex experssion to use in order to get all the desired websites, those that don't have an underscore after the drug name in the form of www.erowid.org/experiences/sub/exp_(drugname).shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing your regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cC4lS4/2), it seems like your regex is identifying the two urls, instead of just the first one.
This leads me to think that there is a problem with your regex (as you stated), instead of a problem with the scrapy regex-engine itself (which should be python's `re` )

Find below, your example with the correct regex. I used specifically characters from a-z and A-Z instead of relying on the "word" symbol.

```
class ExperiencesSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "experiences"
allowed_domains = ["www.erowid.org"]
start_urls = ['https://www.erowid.org/experiences/exp_list.shtml']
rules = [ 
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('subs/exp_[a-zA-Z]+.shtml')), follow = True)
]
def parse_item(self, response):
    pass
```

As `Regex101` shows, the "Word" symbol is known to be: `\w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]` (the underscore is right there, as one of the tokens considered to be part of the `word` symbol)

Another viable approach for your case is to use the [deny() attribute](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml), coupled with your existing `allow()`, and make it so the `deny()` regex knows how to exclude the unwanted urls:

```
class ExperiencesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "experiences"
    allowed_domains = ["www.erowid.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.erowid.org/experiences/exp_list.shtml']
    rules = [ 
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('subs/exp_\w+.shtml')), follow = True),    
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=('subs/exp_[a-zA-Z]+_\w+.shtml')), follow = False)
    ]
    def parse_item(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: Just for info: I did also some tests on regex101 and ended with the following regex: 'subs/exp_[^_]+\.shtml' . Instead of a positive list this yields every url where not a second underscore appears.

Comment: That's also one way to do it. I was trying to figure out how to specify "exp followed by an underscore followed by any word not followed my any other underscore again". I guess that TIL